# Littlewood's theorem on sign changes of $\text{li}-\pi(x)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is there any link to the paper " J. E. Littlewood, Sur la distribution des nombres premiers"? I cannot find anywhere on googling.

What about the analogous to the theorem for small interval? Is there anyway to say that the functions, for $x<x_1$, $\text{li}'(x,x_1):=\text{li}(x_1)-\text{li}(x)$ and $\pi'(x,x_1):=\pi(x_1)-\pi(x)$ possess the same property, which is, for instance, $\text{li}'(x/2,x)-\pi'(x/2,x)$ changes sign infinitely often?

Comment: You can even use [amazon](https://www.amazon.com/DISTRIBUTION-NOMBRES-PREMIERS-Comptes-1869-1875/dp/B001J9RZ22). I also found [free link](https://archive.org/details/comptesrendusheb158acad).

Comment: If you are looking for a proof of this result. Consider reading the modern text _Multiplicative Number Theory I: Classical theory_ by Montgomery & Vaughan